# wifi disabled by hardware switch , ubuntu 13.04, lenovo g580

Tags: wireless, hardware, lenovo

my problem is that I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Lenovo G580 laptop. now Wifi and Bluetooth are not working, it is showing "wifi is disabled by hardware switch".
I tried using dedicated key fn+f5, but didn't work and tried rfkill also.

please help me

Comment: On thinkpad there is a real hardware switch to turn on off wifi, have you checked ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding mine is ideapad and this doesn't have hardware switch.

Comment: What does this report? rfkill list all

Answer (score 0):

On my G570 laptop, their is a small tiny black switch which acts as the hardware switch. This works, and needs to be moved to the right to turn the wireless on. I don't know whether this is the case for the G580.

Comment: Sorry forgot - it is on the front, just to the left of the touchpad, and to the left of the indicator lights